# Get price from object of multiple elements and GetTotal

Tags: java, jsp

I have a collection of product items: `Collection<Products>` that returns items. 'items' below returns an ID and price: [AB123  45.00]
and as elements are added in the basket, increases: [AB123  45.00],[AB124  34.00],[AB123  45.00] etc. The getTotal() method should iterate over contents of the basket to calculate the cost. My question is, how do I get the cost from each item element? This is what I have so far:

```
public double getTotal() {
    double total = 0.0;
    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
    }
    System.out.println(items);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i); // to show index of item. Outputs 0,1,2 etc.
        // do something to add price to variable total

    }
    // return the new total
    return total;
    // this should output total of all items in basket
}
```

Comment: What else would I need @Pshemo

Comment: Could you show us how you add a item into the list so we will know the correct format for extraction ?

Comment: I believe someone gave you excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a getPrice method in your Product class, that gives you the price of a Product object:

```
   public double getTotal() {
        double total = 0.0;
        Iterator<Product> iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            total += iterator.next().getPrice();
        }
        // return the new total
        return total;
    // this should output total of all items in basket
    }
```